# Simple SELECT statement fails with "syntax to use near", "ORA-00906", "syntax error at or near" or "syntax near the keyword"

Tags: sql, select

I have a very simple SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM Table;
```

but, my query engine returns a syntax error. Why?

Error Details:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in >System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

How is this possible? I checked the connection string and it is correct.
I checked my table name and it is also correct.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the name of your table? `table` itself is a reserved word.

Comment: "Table" is a reserved keyword, call your table something else

Comment: If it is called Table, put square brackets round it - [Table] (But also, don't call it table. Change that name!)

Comment: Ow really, i did not know, it was indeed just 'Table'. thank you

Comment: @MichaelB: NO! If it is called `table` then renaming it is the right thing to do. `table` does not say anyting about the content.

Comment: @juergend Yes you are absolutely correct

Comment: ok, thanks everyone, it works now. like i said in the first line. it was a dumb mistake xD. i renamed it to 'Table1'

Comment: @JoJo, in general I would consider making table names more descriptive as to what they represent. What is held in a "Table1"? (unless you are modelling physical tables, but that is an uncommon use case :) )

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yeah i know, but this was just a testing application. it is not something big, just one table with some random numbers ;)

Comment: Just beacause this error results from a 2 character variation, it does not mean this is typograhical error. This is a semantic omission that many have probably encountered in the past. (I have.) The question is also presented correctly, I wish more on SO were too. +1. Closing questions like this seems against the purpose of Stack Overflow (although, I'm suprised its not a duplicate.)

Comment: @Jodrell i always make sure my questions are not duplicate ;) but can someone please tell me WHY is this off-topic???

Comment: @JoJo, for details on why I edited the question, see here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256445/how-can-i-help-a-question-to-get-reopened/256449#256449

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, `Table` is a reserved keyword in all variants of SQL.

If you want to call a table `Table`, and use it in a statement, you have to tell your sql engine that it is an identifier. To do this you need to use **Identifier Qualifiers**.

**for (MS SQL Server) TSQL** use square brackets

```
SELECT * FROM [Table];
```

**for MySQL** use `

```
SELECT * FROM `Table`;
```

**for Oracle and PostgreSQL** use quotation marks,
these are standards compliant.

```
SELECT * FROM "Table";
```

**for SQLite** you can use any of the above, but quotation marks are prefered.

The Identifier Qualifiers tell the engine that this is an identifier (the name of an object.) Not the name of a keyword, even if they happen to be the same. Without your guidance the query engine can get confused and report an error, or worse, do something unexpected.

**Using Identifier Qualifiers is good practice**, even if the identifers are not keywords.
They better define statements for all parsers, including the fleshy kind.

Naming objects after keywords is generally considered bad practice. So you should try to avoid making identifers the same as keywords. The occasions when a reserved keyword is descriptive of the contents of a table are rare, see the footnote.

e.g. your table is not a `Table` of tables.

---

The problem and advice is not limited to `Tables`, Identifiers are required for all database objects inluding `Schema`, `Views` and the many types that exist, standard and vendor-specific.

Another form of good practice is to prefix `Table` indentifiers with a `Schema` identifier, this helps the query engine a little.
When including the `Schema` identifier, the identifer should be qualified,

**for (MS SQL Server) TSQL** use square brackets

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table];
```

**for MySQL** use `

```
SELECT * FROM `dbo`.`Table`;
```

**for Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLite** use quotation marks

```
SELECT * FROM "dbo"."Table";
```

even if your `Schema` is not named after a keyword, as should be the case.

---

For your reference, to help you avoid conflicts.

A list of [TSQL Reserverd Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

A list of [MySQl Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html).

A list of [Oracle Reserved Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

A list of [SQLite Reserved Keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

A list of [PostgreSQL Reserved Keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Notable "gotcha's" include `USER` and `ERROR`, which seem to come up when designing systems.

*Footnote:*

There are occasions when using reseved words for object names may be semantically correct.

Consider the contrived example of an information system for a furniture shop. In this scenario, a table of tables (kitchen, garden, dining, apothecary etc.) may be correct. So, you could argue `Table` was the correct identifier.

If you always use Identifier Qualifiers, you won't get burned.

Comment: thank you! but just renaming the table also worked ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL server you need to wrap table in brackets [] as `table` is keyword in SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This was the first answer and it was correct.

Comment: I don't think it merits a downvote, but it would be nice if it had the "why" piece as in the other answer.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess the downvote was because this was already answered in a comment

Comment: No, the downvote was because it is not clear if MSSQL is used and 2. that is not the way to go. Rename the table. But all that has been already discussed in comments before. So in my opinion your answer is wrong and also obsolete.