# 50894 ERROR reading: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user' when tries to select query to compare the username and password

Tags: java, sql-server, database

```
  public void login(String name,String password) throws SQLException{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;"+"user=looi963;password=1234;database=user");
    PreparedStatement state=conn.prepareStatement("Select username,password from user where username=? and password = ?");
    state.setString(1,name);
    state.setString(2, password );
    int count = state.executeUpdate();
    if(count>0){
        System.out.println("Successful login");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user)

Comment: (Different client language, but same issue)

Comment: Don't use `executeUpdate()` when running a query. Use `executeQuery()` instead. Please read the javadocs of the methods your are using and go through a JDBC tutorial, e.g. the official one from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protect the identifier as [USER is a reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and it cannot be used "bare". Consider the following which uses the `[]`-quotes (`""`-quotes would also work);

```sql
Select username,password from [user] where username = ? and password = ?
```

This error is fairly common (for different reserved words) - make sure to consult the manual. Ideally, I would name the tables and columns such that they are *not* any of the reserved keywords.

---

Also, change `executeUpdate()` to [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) because it's a SELECT operation.

It may also be prudent to switch to a user table that does *not* store the plain-text passwords.. the problem with plain-text passwords is two-fold;

- an unauthorized read on the table *instantly compromises all accounts*, and;
- people often *reuse* passwords which can make their other accounts (eg. email, bank) vulnerable.

Comment: but then, there is another error 55447 ERROR reading: A result set was generated for update. any idea?is it i need a resultset statement to run it?

Comment: @looi963 Make sure to ask different questions for different problems - but search first!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a select query replace this

`state.executeUpdate();` with `ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery()`

then check if records exists with the specified username and password like this

```
if (!rs.next() ) {
    System.out.println("Not valid username and password");
} else {

    do {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+
                           rs.getString(2);


    } while (resultSet.next());
}
```