# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Tags: c#, database, executereader

```
Baglanti.FnkBaglan();
SqlCommand KayitSorgulaUsername = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username FROM User Where Username= @Username AND Username IS NOT NULL ", Baglanti.baglan);
SqlCommand KayitSorgulaMail = new SqlCommand("SELECT Mail FROM DatabaseProje.User Where Mail= @Mail  AND Username IS NOT NULL ", Baglanti.baglan);
KayitSorgulaUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TxtUyeOlUsername.Text);
KayitSorgulaMail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", TxtUyeOlMail.Text);
SqlDataReader VeriOkuUsername = KayitSorgulaUsername.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader VeriOkuMail = KayitSorgulaMail.ExecuteReader();
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

This error appears after I entered the values to textboxes. How can I fix this error?

Comment: @ygzmglkc - are you sure this " DatabaseProje.User " is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User is a reserved word in sql so use it with square brackets, so that it is considered as table name:

```
SELECT Username FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 1):

User is a reserved keyword, so you must use square brackets to make it explicit that you mean the object named "User" it, i.e. use [User] instead of User. Refer to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user)

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the keyword User with brackets: [User]