# Where is the mistake with "INSERT INTO STATEMENT"?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have an Access database that contains a table named **user**. That table has two fields, "username" of shorttext type and "userpassword" of shorttext type as well. The usernameis the primary key!

I made a windows form application, Visual C#, and connected successfully with the database.

I run at first this sql statement in Access,

```
"INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME,USERPASSWORD) VALUES('Tom','1234')"
```

and correctly appends the record into the table.

Now if I try to execute the same sql query through the winform application I get **an exception** which talks about **a** **syntax error in the "Insert into" statement**!

Weird fact is that I have made an application before one week and it worked.

Here is the method that should append the record:

```
public void insertNewUser()
    {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME,USERPASSWORD) VALUES('malmo','1234')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, this.conn);
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        try
        {
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User inserted in database successfully!", "Debug:AppDatabase:insertNewUser");
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User did not inserted in database", "Debug:AppDatabase:insertNewUser");
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Debug:AppDatabase:insertNewUser");
        }
        catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Debug:AppDatabase:insertNewUser");
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected.ToString(), "RowsAffected");
    }
```

I get the Exception in the **second catch block!**

Comment: `USER` is a keyword. use `[USER]` instead.

Comment: User also a keyword? Really now?

Comment: Take a look at this page: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: SQL has keywords just like other languages - `SELECT` for instance.  You should never store passwords as plaintext.

Comment: @RezaAghaei You want to make an answer so I can accept it as the correct one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user)

Comment: @Skemelio Tank you for your offer, your answer is OK. Also the duplicate question linked by Plutonix is useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

USER is a keyword. use [USER] instead. – Reza Aghaei