# lerrorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data from an aspx page to a database but keep getting the error:

errorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DatabaseConnectivity
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegiConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string insertQuery = ("insert into User(firstname,secondname,username,country,console,email,gamertag,password)values (@firstname,@secondname,@username,@country,@console,@email,@gamertag,@password)");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondname", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", TextBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@console", TextBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gamertag", TextBox7.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox8.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Write("User Successfully Registered");

                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is a reserved keyword, so you must use square brackets to make it explicit that you mean the object named **"User"** it, i.e. use **[User]** instead of User.