# Spring JPA cannot save entity with mysql json column using native save method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "DETAILS", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "json" )
    private String details;
}
```

When I receive a new user object I will try to persist it in the database.

```
{
    "age": 5,
    "name": "MARIO",
    "details": "{\"country\":\"Indonesia\"}"
}
```

For some reason I cant save with with the normal JpaRepository save,

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public saveNewUser(User newUser){
    userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

Running the save user function throws me this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'age=5 where name='MARIO'' at line 1
```

But if i define my own custom save method in the repository it saves just fine with no issues:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "insert into USER (NAME, AGE, DETAILS) values (:name, :age, :details)", nativeQuery = true)
void saveWithJson(String name, String details, int age);
```

}

and I call it like so:

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public saveNewUser(User newUser){
    userRepository.saveWithJson(newUser.getName, newUser.getDetails, newUser.getAge);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? I tested with the exact same JSON being received. I dont mind using my own save query, I just assumed that underneath the layer of abstraction JPA should be calling the same method as my native query?

Comment: You can see the exact query JPA is using by enabling debug level log.

Comment: ... to enable sql query traces use `show_sql=true` in the hibernate parameters. The error seems to be the end of a sql  update.

Comment: User is a sql keyword (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082412/sql-error-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user). Try to change the name of your user table.

Comment: @PierreDemeestere yep, that was dumb. This ended up being the issue in the end, because JPA doesnt add quotations on user like what did -> 'user'. Thank youuu

Comment: I am glad I could help you. If you have enough permission to up vote my remark that would help me.

Comment: @PierreDemeestere can you answer so i can select it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the name of table chosen for the entity `User` entity :

`@Table(name = "USER")`

`user` is a sql reserved keyword.

The solution is to choose another name for that table.

Answer (score 0):

Add below property in application.properties file, to view the JPA generated query in console/log

```
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Also verify, is the name already inserted in DB.

Comment: Please refer this working example, https://github.com/jsubhachandra/demo-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "USER")
public class  User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", columnDefinition = "varchar(32) comment 'id:name'")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE", columnDefinition = "int(3) comment 'age'")
    private Integer age;

    @Column(name = "DETAILS", columnDefinition = "text comment 'details'")
    private String details;
}


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    
}

public UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveNewUser(User newUser) {
        userRepository.save(newUser);
    }
}
```